# How do you select the nth item in a list based on that item’s child's attributes using only CSS selectors

Tags: css, list, css-selectors

So if I have a list like this:

```
<ul>
 <li><button disabled/></li>
 <li><button disabled/></li>
 <li><button /></li>
 <li><button /></li>
 <li><button /></li>
</ul>
```

And the amount of disabled buttons is never known - but will always be consecutive and appear before the enabled buttons, how do I select the second enabled button?

Right now I have:

- `“ul li:nth-of-type(2) button:not([disabled])”`

but this only selects the second `<li>` with a child button that is not disabled - if it is disabled, it doesn’t select anything.
In other words it doesn’t ‘find’ the second enabled button, it just checks if the second button is enabled or not and selects it accordingly.

I’ve tried

- `“ul li button:not([disabled]):nth-of-type(2)”`

but the problem with that is the button is the only child of `<li>`, so nth-of-type(2) doesn’t have anything to select.

What I think I need to be able to write is something like this:

- `“ul (li button:not([disabled])):nth-of-type(2)”`

but I don’t think that’s the correct syntax :(

Any help would be greatly appreciated! If it helps anyone, I'm writing a UDF test to find (and select) the second available time slot for a time picker component in React.

Comment: I can get you as far as `li:has(button:not(:disabled)) {...}` but haven't successfully managed to connect that to nth-of-type yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way you can do it using `:has()` which now looks to have support in all updated browsers (thanks FF for catching up):

```css
button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}


/* Second */

li:has(button[disabled])+li:has(button:not([disabled]))+li:has(button:not([disabled])) button {
  background: red;
}


/* first */

li:has(button[disabled])+li:has(button:not([disabled])) button {
  background: blue;
}


/* third */

li:has(button[disabled])+li:has(button:not([disabled]))+li:has(button:not([disabled]))+li:has(button:not([disabled])) button {
  background: green;
}


/* no disabled buttons per comment by haolt */

li:first-child:has(button:not([disabled]))+li:has(button:not([disabled])) button {
  background: purple;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><button disabled/></li>
  <li><button disabled/></li>
  <li><button /></li>
  <li><button /></li>
  <li><button /></li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li><button /></li>
  <li><button /></li>
  <li><button /></li>
  <li><button /></li>
  <li><button /></li>
</ul>
```

It's not very elegant, as we are chaining next sibling `+` selectors, but it works.

Comment: Only one small thing, in case there are no disabled buttons: `li:first-child:has(button:not([disabled]))+li:has(button:not([disabled])) button`

Comment: absolutely genius, thank you. In my case, there may be 0 disabled buttons so I deleted the first part `li:has(button[disabled])+` 
edit: what @haolt said

Comment: Ah, yeah, good catch if there were no disabled buttons! Added to the answer for completeness. Good call @haolt

Comment: @haolt even though this got you what you needed, you may want to mark Temani's as the accepted answer, it's much simpler and clean.

Comment: @disinfor Look like you tagged the wrong guy, I'm not OP :) I agree that it's more elegant and easier to read, just be careful with browser support. All major browsers only had supported it since early/mid 2023 (except Safari - 2015)

Comment: Ha! Sure did! @PrestonMoore - meant to tag you. Temani's answer is much cleaner, but beware of what haolt said.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an easier selector where you only have to update one number to select the needed button

```css
li:nth-child(2 of :has(button:not([disabled]))) button {
  color: red;
}
li:nth-child(3 of :has(button:not([disabled]))) button {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
 <li><button disabled>button</button></li>
 <li><button disabled>button</button></li>
 <li><button >button</button></li>
 <li><button >button</button></li>
 <li><button >button</button></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Oh snap! This is a great solution! I figured you'd have a better one. :)